# Is it possible to postpone the delivery of a post on a wall? (using Facebook IOS SDK)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, facebook, sdk

I will click 'post' and then I will close the app, but I want the post to be delivered after 1hour. Is it possible or How can I do this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible.  You can request up to 10 minutes of background execution time, but that's it.  The only way to do something after an hour is display a local notification that prompts your user to re-open the app.  You can't force them to do it though.